# Length of an array using sizeof

Tags: c, sizeof

I am trying to determine the length of an array using the sizeof function.

My code looks like this:

```
int n;
n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

I keep getting a warning saying that this type is inconsistent. I understand this but how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Please tag a programming language. Is this c++?

Comment: can you also please include the exact error,

Comment: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘a’ will return size of ‘int*’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
     printf(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));

Comment: This is in C programming language

Comment: Show the definition of `a`. Is it an array?

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `a` is a function parameter, and `sizeof(a)` will return the size of `int*` instead of the actual size of the array. The reason for this is because function parameters of array types are actually exactly the same thing as pointers (so a parameter of type `int[]` is actually just a parameter of type `int*`) and the size specified in the array type is just information for the reader, not something the compiler actually enforces.

The `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` trick is really only suitable for use by macros, not something you should be writing in non-macro code, because if you're in a context where it's possible to statically know the length of the array (e.g. it didn't come from a function parameter) then you should already know what it is without having to compute it.

Comment: I see where you're driving with your last paragraph, but there's an important case where you don't have the size around except by using the expression: `SomeType array[] = { { ... }, { ... }, ... };`.  The size of the array is determined by the number of initializers, and the only ways to determine that are by the expression or by using a sentinel value to mark the end of the list.

Comment: So then how do I find the length of an input array without using a for loop

Comment: @user7942759: pass the array length as a separate parameter.

Comment: @user7942759 you can't find the length of an array with a `for` loop, unless the last element of the array has a unique value that you'd be checking for.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid warning type casting is used i.e `(int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))`

Comment: That may suppress the warning, but that's not a good thing. The expression will just end up evaluating to `1` or `2` depending on whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture.

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting a warning saying that this type is inconsistent.

```
// OP's code
int n;
n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

`n` is an `int`.  The result type of `sizeof` is `size_t`, some *unsigned* type.  An `int` often has less range than `size_t` or `[0...SIZE_MAX]`. Hence a warning about type inconsistency.

```
// Alternative
size_t n;
n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
printf("Element Count: %zu\n", n);
```